# Copying Values and excluding #N/A cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code that copies cells from one excel sheet and pastes special values into a text file.

now from the sheet I'm copying, I have a lot of cells which contain #N/A.

can anyone suggest how to exclude these cells?

thanks

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim NewWB As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range


On Error Resume Next

i = Sheets(1).Range("W158:W" & Range("W158").End(xlDown).Row).Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set NewWB = Application.Workbooks.Add
Thispath = wb.path

wb.Sheets(2).Range("W158:W" & i + 5).Copy
NewWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
NewWB.SaveAs filename:=Thispath & "\textfile.txt", FileFormat:=xlText, 
CreateBackup:=False
NewWB.Close

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to leave an empty cell in the destination for bad cells in the source or do you want the non-error cells filled in compactly??

Comment: Since it's going to paste values in a text document it can just exclude. So it will paste the first value found in the source and then the next one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of is to do a basic for loop to go through all the cells individually and check for their value

```
For Each cell In activehseet.Range("W158:W" & i + 5)
    With cell
        If .Value = "#N\A" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            .Copy
            'code to paste here
        End With
    Next cell
```

This unfortunately would take quite a while to run and would only get longer the larger the size of the database. I would suggest losing any rows/columns that aren't in use to speed this up.

However it is probably the easiest method to fix your problem

It could be possible by using an array but as I am not an expert with array manipulation i couldn't be sure. I'm sure someone a lot smarter than me could help you through that

Hope this helps get you started. Great question!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your formulas in `IFERROR`, just select all cells which you want to wrap and run the following macro:

```
Sub WrapFormulasWIthIFERROR()
  Dim Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In Selection
    If Cell.HasFormula Then
      If Left(Cell.Formula, 9) <> "=IFERROR(" Then
        Cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid(Cell.Formula, 2) & ","""")"
      End If
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

If the cell value is N/A, the result will be an empty cell. Just be aware to not select the whole sheet, because it will run forever.